# UK child visitor visa for Scotland

Tags: visas, uk

I have a ten-year UK Child Visitor visa, and I'm an Indian citizen. I'm making a trip to Scotland next month to participate in a ten day [leadership camp](http://www.tgelf.org/student-leadership-challenge-in-scotland-uk-columba-1400/).

**Can I make this trip with my existing visa?**

Comment: Is the visa still valid? Are you still a child?

Comment: Yes it's a valid visa till 2016. Also a UK child visa is valid for the visa term even after the holder turns 18.

Comment: I wondered if my visa covered the fact that I'm taking a course there, or if I needed a student visa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [www.gov.uk](https://www.gov.uk/child-visit-visa/overview):

> What you can and can’t do
>
> You can:
>
> - stay in the UK for a maximum of 6 months
> - **take a short course of study, for up to 6 months**
> - stay for as long as your visa lasts, even if you turn 18 during your visit
>
> You can’t:
>
> - work
> - get married or form a civil partnership
> - bring family members (‘dependants’) with you on your application - they must apply separately
> - get private medical treatment
> - get public funds

so it's not a problem to visit Scotland and take part in a ten day leadership camp.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I'm surprised about the private medical treatment point. Am I permitted to be treated at a state-run hospital?

Comment: @VedantChandra You can get emergency medical care if you need it; the point of that restriction is that the _purpose_ of your visit on the Child Visitor visa cannot be to seek medical care.