# Turning 18, visitor visa UK

Tags: visas, uk, moroccan-citizens

My sister in law came to the UK with her mum and dad in April 2014 for a couple of weeks on a 6-month family visitor visa. They returned to Morocco on 23 April. She wants to come back to the UK this July during the summer holidays. When she applied for the visa it was as a child and her visa states that she must be accompanied. However since returning to Morocco she has turned 18 and will be travelling alone to the UK.

- Does she need to be accompanied if she comes here again?
- Does she require a new visa as an adult?
- Can she travel unaccompanied to the UK on the same visa?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UK child visitor visa for Scotland](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/27874/uk-child-visitor-visa-for-scotland)

Comment: the Scotland reply doesnt state if she can travel alone or needs to be accompanied by the adult whom she specified in the visa application

Answer (score 5):

The [official site](https://www.gov.uk/child-visit-visa/travelling-with-an-adult) seems pretty clear:

> When travelling to the UK with an adult (someone over the age of 18) you’ll need to identify them in your visa application.
>
> Their name will appear on your visa, and you’ll be refused entry to the UK if you arrive in the UK without them.

A child visa can definitely be used to stay in the UK after one's 18th birthday. I guess it could also be used to re-enter the UK, although I am not sure, but it doesn't matter here as your sister-in-law does not have a visa to travel alone.